# R shiny datatable custom action when clicking on excel button

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have an R datatable within a shiny app. More specifically, I have the following code:

```
tmp = head(mtcars)
datatable(tmp, extensions='Buttons', options=list(dom = 'Blfrtip', buttons=c('excel')))
```

This allows users to click on 'excel' and download the data.
I would need to track how many users click on that excel button.
So the question is: how can we trigger some custom code when a user clicks on that 'excel' button?
I know there are other ways to add a download to excel (or csv) button, but this datatable format (with dom = 'Blfrtip') is what is used across the entire shiny app.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      extensions = "Buttons",
      options = list(
        dom = "Bfrtip",
        buttons = list(
          list(
            extend = "excel",
            customize = JS(
              "function() {",
              "  Shiny.setInputValue('click', true, {priority: 'event'});",
              "}"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  clicks <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$click, {
    clicks(clicks() + 1)
  })
  
  observe({ # print number of clicks on the Excel button
    print(clicks())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you @stephane, this works like a charm. The only question I would have is: would there be a way to do it, combining observe, observeEvent and clicks() into one single "function"? meaning, would it be possible to have everything inside "observe"?